# Video lectures about data mining?

Tags: references, data-mining

I want to learn data mining.  Are there any free video lectures out there which explain the process of data mining in depth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- David Mease has a [Statistics / Data Mining Course](http://www.stats202.com/) brought to you by Google with full videos. It is introductory and from what I've seen of the first few videos appears to use R and Excel to demonstrate ideas.

Comment: sir, this link is asking for username and password to see the videos for the year 2011 :D

Comment: @Ant's At least the 2007 videos are still accessible, and but for the videos, the 2011 course materials are also accessible.

Comment: Yup only course materials are accessible but not the videos :)

Answer (score 12):

The [PASCAL Project's video library](http://videolectures.net/Top/Computer_Science/Data_Mining/) (PASCAL is *Pattern Analysis, Statistical Modelling and Computational Learning*).

I have never found anything that even comes close--either in the number of videos, in the average quality, or in scope.

The Project scope is Machine Learning; each video lecture is annotated with one or more tags which represent hierarchical subject-matter rubrics. For "Data Mining" there are at least several relevant tags:

- Data Mining
- Text Mining
- Semantic Web
- Web Mining

Here's the best part: aside from these subject-matter categories, there is an orthogonal classification which you access from the left-hand side panel, and which relates to the lecture *format*, e.g., *Lecture*, *Keynote*, *Interview*, and of perhaps most interest for you, ***Tutorial***. This is one of the largest categories and includes videos that survey/introduce the entire discipline of Machine Learning (e.g., [Introduction to Machine Learning)](http://videolectures.net/aibootcamp2011_quinn_iml/) to more advanced tutorials on individual ML techniques.

A few suggestions for use:

The [Computer Science](http://videolectures.net/Top/Computer_Science/) category is perhaps the best top-level category to begin searching or browsing for videos of interest to you (for Data Mining).

Every Video includes a set of *slides*. I would recommend downloading the slide set and accessing from your local drive during the video which saves bandwidth plus you can annotate the slides with notes as you wish.

When you scan the videos, look for the solid yellow stars that appear down the left-hand side of the thumbnail image of each video--those are the rating for each video.

Finally, you might want to try browsing the library this way: begin at the highest level (all videos); then in the left-hand side panel, select *Tutorial*, moving down, then select *Highest Rated*, then select the *languages*. These selections will only affect your results *order* (the order in which the videos are shown to you as thumnail images in your browser).

Answer (score 7):

Andrew Ng's Stanford University course on Machine learning is [available on YouTube, iTunes and Stanford Engineering Everywhere](http://www.cs.stanford.edu/people/ang/courses.html).

Answer (score 4):

Tom Mitchell's Machine learning course at Carnegie Mellon University has [video lectures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10701_sp11/lectures.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

This video series on machine learning looks good:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0F06AA0D2E8FFBA&feature=plcp